# How do I compile sass imports automatically when I have edited them?

Tags: sass, codekit

Im using [Codekit](https://incident57.com/codekit) to compile my sass, and Im splitting parts of my website into individual sass files so when it comes to editing I can easily find the file I'm looking for, But I've noticed that when I edit an import I have to go back to the main.sass style sheet and re-save so that it recompiles my changes, my question is, is their a way to automatically compile my main.sass file upon edit of an import ?

```
Main.sass

@import 'scss_files/_styles.sass'
@import 'scss_files/_service.sass'
@import 'scss_files/_outsource.sass'
@import 'scss_files/_branding.sass'
@import 'scss_files/_wordsearch.sass'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is an error. Try to remove the file extensions of your imports (`.sass`) because in sass there is no need to include the file extension if you are importing a file